# Fatal error in Facebook app: Call to a member function getLongLivedSession() on a non-object

Tags: php, curl, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a PHP script that posts content on Facebook page of an user. This works through a Facebook app.

When I click Authorize, it loads for 10 seconds, it doesn't post and it shows a blank page with the following error:

```
exception Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:f01f:2:face:b00c:0:2: Network is  unreachable Fatal error: Call to a member function getLongLivedSession() on a non-object in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/mysite/thirdparty/networks/facebook/Facebook.php on line 92
```

Everything worked perfectly until a week ago, but today I continue to get that error. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: I'm having problems, too. When I'm using IPv6 adresses. Maybe a week ago you still had an IPv4 address?

Comment: I'll try to force curl to ipv4 only. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Same problem since this morning. This comes from a standalone PHP script using Facebook methods so it's not really possible to use curl_setopt. Is there a global php.ini setting ? PS: not all requests fail.

Comment: @AlainZelink: I’m afraid you’d have to modify the script itself then. (Are we talking about the old Facebook PHP SDK v3, or something else?) But in general, this is rather an issue of network configuration, and should be investigated and fixed as such, and not by forcing cURL to “downgrade” to IPv4.

Comment: Could you try using IPv4 instead of IPv6?

Comment: I'm using Facebook-4.4.0 SDK. Here is the type of calls which (sometimes) fail : $events = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/events?limit=500&since=now'))->execute()->getGraphObject('GraphEventList'); - This has been working for the last 2 months and suddenly (since this morning) I've randomly had IPV6 failures. If I restart, the failures happen for other calls.

Answer (score 4):

Many servers have IPv6 enabled but it’s not routed and it doesn’t actually work. This turns into a major issue when you are trying to access a site which is IPv6 ready. By default, curl will try to connect via IPv6 and will timeout. Via IPv4 it could work just fine, only if you add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

If you encounter this problem with `file_get_contents()`, `get_headers()`, etc. you can add the following lines in `/etc/sysctl.conf` :

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Or

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

## Update based on your comments:

Disable ipv6 in **freebsd 9**

```
/etc/rc.conf


ipv6_network_interfaces="none" # Default is auto

ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="NO" # this is the default

ip6addrctl_enable="NO" # New way to disable IPv6 support

ip6addrctl_policy="ipv4_prefer" # Use IPv4 instead of IPv6

ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="NO" # Do not automatically add IPv6 addresses
```

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this answer previously. I'm running FreeBSD so this conf doesn't work for me. I'm going to check how to disable it globally for FreeBSD and give it a go. curl_setopt is not an option since I'm using Facebook methods.

Comment: If you're using Facebook methods, go with the last option (Disable ipv6 in freebsd 9).

Comment: Hello. I changed the rc.conf & rebooted but still have errors. I checked the man page for rc.conf and everything seems OK. Maybe there's an option missing. BTW ipv6_activate_all_interfaces is specified twice in your comment. I'm running FreeBSD 9.2.